# How to use Slim Image Cropper in CakePHP framework?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

everyone. I recent bought this plugin; `Slim Image Cropper`
(https://pqina.nl/slim/).

However, I don’t know how to use it with `cakephp` (3.x) framework.

Does anyone know how to use this plugin before?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean by how to use it? Flagged as unclear.

Comment: It's advertised as "JavaScript plug-in". Is your question really specific to CakePHP? Do you know how to use the plug-in in the context of static HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you contact the plugin developer/support for the plugin and ask them for instructions...or perhaps they offer setup as a paid service.

Also, if you can't add a JavaScript snippet into a layout/view then it sounds like you still have some learning to do, which is totally fine! We all started somewhere. But Web development isn't putting pre-built pieces together...you need to know the foundations of the languages your using first. But I'm just going off the ambiguous question

However, I would:

1. Place the JS plugin files in webroot
2. Link to them in layout (or view) using cake's Html helper
3. Follow instructions here: https://pqina.nl/slim/#easy-configuration

Hope that helps